# Find all files where other files with different extension dont already exist

Tags: ubuntu, bash, find

I want to use the find command, to find all files with a certain extension (avi), where the same filename with another extension (mp4) does not already exist.

so considering these files:

```
a.avi
a.mp4
c.avi
```

it should only result in the file c.avi being found.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @and31415 ubuntu server

Answer (score 1):

Would this do?

```
find . -name '*.avi' -type f -execdir bash -c 'f=("${0%avi}"*);((${#f[@]}==1))' {} \; -print
```

I'll try to explain how it works.

Well, in fact it's really easy: find all files in current directory such that the name has `avi` extension. For each of these, say it's file `X.avi` execute in the directory there're in (`execdir`) the command:

```
bash -c 'f=("${0%avi}"*);((${#f[@]}==1))' {}
```

where `{}` is replaced by the file name, in our test case `X.avi`. So this is like

```
bash -c 'f=("${0%avi}"*);((${#f[@]}==1))' X.avi
```

At this point, let me stress that this is 100% safe regarding spaces and other funny symbols in file names! Now you see the snippet that bash will execute? I mean this snippet

```
f=("${0%avi}"*);((${#f[@]}==1))
```

It will be executed with the 0-th positional parameter set to our file name; in our test example it's `X.avi`.

The part `"${0%avi}"` expands to the filename, with trailing `avi` removed (btw, this file name is guaranteed to have this extension at this point), and the part `"${0%avi}"*` will expand to all files in current directory (remember, the one containing the file) that have the `.avi` extension. In our test example this is just like:

```
X.*
```

We then build an array `f` out of these, and, finally, we exit this `bash` process with success if `f` contains only one element (so, very likely, `f` only contains `X.avi` in our test example), and failure otherwise. If this was a success, we print the file name.

Comment: Excuse me, but if you downvote, leave a message. It's very likely that you didn't grasp the full depth of my answer, and I'll be happy to give you some clarification about it. And you might even learn something in the process! `:D`

Comment: I didn’t downvote, but I’m tempted to. I doubt that this will work, but I don’t have access to a \*nix system right now, so I can’t test it. (Have ***you*** tested it?) Please explain how/why you believe that this works, and prepare to learn something yourself when somebody comes along and tells you why it doesn’t.

Comment: @Scott, please come back when you have a *nix system available, and we'll have a little chat. In the meantime, feel free to downvote, but if you do so, please spend 2 minutes to clear your doubts that it _doesn't_ work, make it a certitude with a robust reasoning (if you can, haha).

Comment: Maybe you're not comfortable with bash parameter expansions (hey, after all, we're on SU, not like we were on a site with knowledgeable guys); if that's the case, delete your comment. Let me tell you I believe it is the case, because anyone who knows bash at least a little bit will understand this trivial snippet.

Answer (score 1):

A solution with 2 exec()s:

```
find . -name '*.avi' -print | \
  perl -n -e '$x = $_; $x =~ s/\.avi\s*$/.mp4/; (-e $x) || print'
```

Steps:

1. these **are** the droids you're looking for
2. for every input line/file, test for a corresponding .mp4 file and echo the .avi filename if not found

   1. copy the input line to $x
   2. substitute .mp4 for .avi in $x (but only  at end-of-line)
   3. if the corresponding .mp4 file exists we're done with this line, otherwise print the input line

Answer (score 0):

Another option: find all `.mp4` and `.avi` files, then eliminate from the list any files for which both extensions exist, and then eliminate the remaining .mp4 files:

```
find . -name '*.avi' -or -name '*.mp4' |
rev | sort -t. -k2 -k1,1 | uniq -s3 -u | grep -v '^4pm' | rev | sort
```

(Assumes that no file has a newline in its name.)

Answer (score -1):

A solution with 3 exec()s:

```
find . -name '*.avi' -print | \
  sed 's/\(.*\)\.avi$/if [ ! -f "\1.mp4" ]; then echo "\1.avi"; fi/' | \
  sh
```

Steps:

1. these **are** the droids you're looking for
2. strip off the .avi file extension; write a stream of sh commands that tests for a corresponding .mp4 file and echos the .avi filename if not found
3. evaluate the sh commands

Comment: I wish I could `touch '" ]; then rm -rf /; [ ! -f ".avi'`. Surprise `:D`.

Comment: Arguments for/against this pipeline. Pro: dead simple, so easily adapted. Con: this pipeline could do bad things under pathological circumstances (as in gniourf_gniourf's example). So running with root privileges without further checks would be a bad idea.